# Toggle Button To Expanding Navigation Menu On Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on the menu anchor element it takes me back to the top of the page. As I scroll through the site I would like the menu to stay at the section that I have scrolled to when I click the menu anchor. I would like the menu anchor to only act as an open and close function of the expanding nav. [

```js
function openMenu() {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.width = "608px"
    document.getElementById('content').style.marginLeft = "608px"
  }

function closeMenu() {
  document.getElementById('menu').style.width = "0px"
  document.getElementById('content').style.marginLeft = "0px"
}
```

```css
:root {
      --main-color: #FEFF66;  
      --second-color: #000000;
      --third-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
.slide {
  margin: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
}
 .slide a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--second-color);
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
.help a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--second-color);
}

.help {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--third-color);
  color: var(--second-color);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.links {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.header-menu {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  margin: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">

  <span class="slide">
      <a href="#" onclick="openMenu()">MENU</a>
    </span>

  <div id="menu" class="help">
    <div><a class="header-menu" href="#" onclick="closeMenu()">MENU</a></div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#story">OUR STORY</a><br>
      <a href="#rooms">ROOMS + BOOK</a><br>
      <a href="#neighbourhood">THE NEIGHBOURHOOD</a><br>
      <a href="#art">THE ART</a><br>
      <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yipTL.png)

Comment: in your menu link change `href="#"` to `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Answer (score 0):

On your click listener pass in the event received as follow:

```
<div><a class="header-menu" href="#" onclick="closeMenu($event)">MENU</a></div>
```

The `$event` in the template has a special meaning in this case.

Then, on your `closeMenu` function adjust accordingly and prevent the default behavior of browser for anchor elements.

```
// Here, the function parameter can be named whatever you like,
// I named it "event" but anything else would work.
function closeMenu(event) {
  // The line below will prevent the default behavior of the browser
  // for this element and event, which means, it scroll to anywhere
  // in this case, nor redirect to another page in case you had a URL
  // in the href attribute.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `event.preventDefault();` inside your javascript.

```
function openMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('menu').style.width = "608px"
    document.getElementById('content').style.marginLeft = "608px"
}
```

This prevent default actions of object you clicked, in this case anchor tag.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault?retiredLocale=it